# Interpreting RA-4 sensitometry charts

Tags: color, darkroom, paper, sensitivity

I'm having problems with interpreting RA-4 color negative paper sensitometry charts, more precisely it's density readings.

Especially what would a spectrometer see with a paper exposed to D<sub>max</sub>.

I see that DH curve, but that one is usually measured with **Status A** filters, but what would the actual spectrum reflectivity of the dye be? I'm especially confused that I noticed at least three ways to express that.

There seems to be a way [3] does it - that the diffuse density graphs goes to about 1.5D, but its characteristic curves go up to ~2.5D. Then there's [1], where it seemd to be relativized to D=1, but I'm still unsure on how to interpret that - If I were to take a spectrometer to that, or better, if I were to calculate/simulate the way its dyes would reflect a particular light, how would  I calculate that? And there's the [2], which doesn't indicate that it's relative to D=1, but the spectral dye density peaks are suspiciously close to 1D.

Simply put, If I were to trace the data to the computer, how would I calculate the reflected amount of some light source based on it's sensitometry data preseted in those technical data sheets?

---

[1] https://125px.com/docs/paper/kodak/e23.pdf (pg 5)

[2] https://125px.com/docs/paper/kodak/e4044.pdf (pg 7)

[3] https://125px.com/docs/paper/kodak/e140.pdf (pg 5).

Answer (score 0):

Photo papers have multiple emulsion coats applied over a highly reflective substrate called a Baryta. The name comes from barium sulphate, the initial reflective coat used. Today this coat might be manmade.

Color paper uses a subtractive system. Light from an adjacent source play on the color paper. This light must traverse the emulsion coats that contain dyes. These are the subtractive primaries cyan, magenta, and yellow.

Cyan is a red-light blocker (absorber). Magenta is a green-light blocker. Yellow is a blue-light blocker. These dyes are imbedded in the three emulsion coats above the Baryta coat. The dye laydown is in proportion to the original colors of the subject (vista).

As the light from the adjacent source traverses the color print, these dyes take their toll absorbing red, green and blue from the viewing light.

A key fact, the viewing light thus makes two transits through the dyes. One incoming and one outgoing after reflecting off the Baryta. Because there are two transits through the dyes, the density of dyes laid down is about one-half of the dyes deposited in photo color films.

Comment: What you've written is technically true, but I understand that already. I was looking more for mathematical/densitometric/spectroscopy interpretation of the charts.